# How do I properly set the image size in jsPDF so that the image isn't blurry?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to include an image in a PDF I'm generating with jsPDF, but the image comes out blurry. How can I avoid this and get a sharp image?

This is what the generated PDF looks like

[image: pdf screenshot]

I've tried telling jsPDF that the image is 160x60px, but it actually comes out as 285x107 pixels. Also, jsPDF says the page is 446.46 px wide. But if I measure the screenshot it's actually 793 px wide. What's going on here?

This is the code I'm running ([jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6htnzja8/) so that you can play around with it if you want)

```js
function pdf() {
  const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
  
  const imgData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAAA8CAMAAADWtUEnAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAzUExURQB/DtjY2CZF9wAm/6Kr4YKR5wBRiWl87DxX81Fp8ABHpBM2+wAu6QA+ugBoSQBbbQA10ySBQ2kAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAANaSURBVGhDzVeBkqswCKymVq3ttf//tY+FkETROzqvM8iMtwKbLcZIcpfzWyd2WnQTo9BNjEI3MQrdxCh0E6PQTYzC85tWelZ0E6PQTYxCNzEK3cQodBOj0E2MwvObVmqwT1dGsYpDgt2K33UjAlP1/0JRGIvfKhi+CQjMGLFX4B0JWPYp3reRLd8iS8OyT9YoGL4VyM9DQjsFLiktfFPjeaavktjwLWaFNg4FQlYwfBOga+EBewWm9GBs4nMaGEl/ZhQ7QvuA9EOkAB8KW/4va3CnwCXNhpd6wa6bdl/RGklBbpo4K7BPChv+ZwXOO094kwmEP2Ddb/NrnNOdsY2PrMA+KZhxJlDQFohH3fKe+Ws5yq8x9TbOE3+cP7Z7+sl32W7ple8ae7/zDdn7IfjiT5ITT769cfgDhda0UoNmBvvt1wd7yBJkH3MBlD7HiYlv9dWTwnb8pVuYKP6UTN4OUDQFLuikb/wgJTT+aBq0Foi7JyP5s1TKcVJAW4KCjqcCmwb9XwWiCcjcYHY0vjeDZLksrFF5AsShIK+fFgBHEf/aDF7TdM3CtC1p/KBA2nE40bdtRRQ43myNXytwSNOSBvHH9GI8LvAyoiP3q7YiCuLX9vTFArHas9/rKzosEPxl3degUA4ZvQz86ivG28n+TLWwHReIesoDMUKh+Fnh7wIPzfTB1ARKsu1cmy6Gb2Et8akCm1ZqcDuD9Hh1Kysz+GSWxJsZxukmXen6UR9/SKHkywxOze/s7SR6Y9AUSGu8+LOeal6omozz9MUq/0eOk0k/Co6TguYvs55qeAvXvD2MmEBBU6Ce22BLacSyhBDvMSc5T+tPbh71MEHW1xmV/ow4K3CeFPL4iiZQ0BY4UOcQfypthtoJV4BTST0PjvXcSF8yI3tDiT9r4ayAPBSEp3xCEyhoC6S6eAZoadVXRY/NhbVbGvVAkxeXFKAKBQkgDgYhK9RxGU2ALtnh1SCoec3UrY6QDvFs6tOvw7jePKAsDZo5sbrVkTUKja6gCdB1XCBWPVl+JTAg/xtUt7RfC7xkhXZ8q7COE57ftNKzopsYhW5iFLqJUegmRqGbGIVuYhSe37TSs6KbGIVuYhS6iVHoJkahmxiFbmIUnt+00rOimxiFbmIIdt0/eH4pjf9qBVQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
  const imgWidth = 160;
  const imgHeight = 60;
  const margin = 40;
  const doc = new jsPDF("p", "px", "a4");
  const pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  console.log("pageWidth", pageWidth);
  
  doc.addImage(
    imgData,
    "PNG",
    pageWidth / 2 - imgWidth / 2,
    margin,
    imgWidth,
    imgHeight
  );
  
  doc.save("img.pdf")
}
```

How can I make the image render with its actual size of 160x60 px so that it's not blurry?

**EDIT:**

Knowing that the generated pdf is actually 793 pixels wide I can calculate the factor jsPDF is wrong by, by doing `pageWidth / 793`. If I use this factor to scale the width and height parameters of the image it displays correctly!

```js
  const imgWidth = 160 * pageWidth / 793;
  const imgHeight = 60 * pageWidth / 793;
  
  doc.addImage(
    imgData,
    "PNG",
    pageWidth / 2 - imgWidth / 2,
    margin,
    imgWidth,
    imgHeight
  );
```

[image: pdf screenshot, correct img size]

But I worry that this is going to break on other devices. Like perhaps devices with a different DPI. I want a more robust implementation that doesn't rely on my magic 793 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the `px_scaling` hotfix makes it work as expected. https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/HOTFIX_README.md

See also the discussion in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2927

HackbrettXXX links a [comment](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2781#issuecomment-648060887) there that's also relevant:

> As you can see here, the scaleFactor is set to a fixed value of 1pt = 96/72 px. It does not factor in the device PPI/DPI. This behavior is "correct", since we can argue that PDF is a print medium and CSS sets the pixel ratio for print media to 1px = 1/96in